# Dig Connection Error on SRV Records

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, kerberos, dig

Using Bind9 running on localhost.
I have two records in my DNS zone file:

```
_kerberos._udp.GROUP-42.SNOOPY.ISP  IN  SRV 0 0 88 kirby.group-42.snoopy.isp.
kirby.group-42.snoopy.isp.          IN  A          10.44.42.129
```

I can run `dig kirby.group-42.snoopy.isp` and get back a correct answer of `10.44.42.129`, but when I try to run `dig _kerberos._udp.GROUP-42.SNOOPY.ISP SRV` is get an error saying that the connection has timed out or no severs could be reached.

Why does it work for the A record but not the SRV record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a "." at the end of "_kerberos._udp.GROUP-42.SNOOPY.ISP", so named is appending the zone origin to the end of that string because it is not a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN).

Consequently you don't have a record for "_kerberos._udp.GROUP-42.SNOOPY.ISP" you have a record for "_kerberos._udp.GROUP-42.SNOOPY.ISP.$ORIGIN"  ($ORIGIN will be either the name of the containing zone (the default) or whatever you have set it to if you have defined a different origin in the zone master file.)

Try putting a "." at the end of the record label, increment the zone serial number in the SOA, and reload the zone.

EDIT:  You may also have another problem, as the lack of a record in your zone should not result in a timeout doing a query for that record.  But fix the missing "." first, and then if you are still having problems post *the entire output* from the failing dig command.  The result is important, as is the server section.  It wouldn't hurt to use the "dig @server" syntax to specify the server you are asking, or dig +trace, either..